# Convert datetime back to Windows 64-bit FILETIME

Tags: python, python-2.x, filetime

I would like to create network timestamps in NT format.

I've been able to convert them to readable time with this function:

```
NetworkStamp = "\xc0\x65\x31\x50\xde\x09\xd2\x01"

def GetTime(NetworkStamp):
    Ftime = int(struct.unpack('<Q',NetworkStamp)[0])
    Epoch = divmod(Ftime - 116444736000000000, 10000000)
    Actualtime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(Epoch[0])
    return Actualtime, Actualtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

print GetTime(NetworkStamp)
```

Output:

```
(datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 8, 11, 35, 57), '2016-09-08 11:35:57')
```

Now I'd like to do the opposite, converting `'2016/09/08 11:35:57'` sec to this format:

```
 "\xc0\x65\x31\x50\xde\x09\xd2\x01"
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code that converts the Window's `FILETIME` value into a `datetime.datetime` isn't as accurate as it could be—it's truncating any fractional seconds there might have been (because it ignores the remainder of the `divmod()` result). This isn't noticeable in the readable string your code creates since it only shows whole seconds.
    Even if the fractional seconds are included, you can't do exactly what you want because the Windows `FILETIME` structure has values in intervals of 100-nanosecond (.1 microsecond), but Python's `datetime` only supports accuracy to whole microseconds. So best that's possible to do is approximate the original value due to this loss of information involved even doing the most accurate possible conversion.

Here's code, for both Python 2 and 3, demonstrating this using the `NetworkStamp` test value in your question:

```
import datetime
import struct
import time

WINDOWS_TICKS = int(1/10**-7)  # 10,000,000 (100 nanoseconds or .1 microseconds)
WINDOWS_EPOCH = datetime.datetime.strptime('1601-01-01 00:00:00',
                                           '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
POSIX_EPOCH = datetime.datetime.strptime('1970-01-01 00:00:00',
                                         '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
EPOCH_DIFF = (POSIX_EPOCH - WINDOWS_EPOCH).total_seconds()  # 11644473600.0
WINDOWS_TICKS_TO_POSIX_EPOCH = EPOCH_DIFF * WINDOWS_TICKS  # 116444736000000000.0

def get_time(filetime):
    """Convert windows filetime winticks to python datetime.datetime."""
    winticks = struct.unpack('<Q', filetime)[0]
    microsecs = (winticks - WINDOWS_TICKS_TO_POSIX_EPOCH) / WINDOWS_TICKS
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(microsecs)

def convert_back(timestamp_string):
    """Convert a timestamp in Y=M=D H:M:S.f format into a windows filetime."""
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    posix_secs = int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
    winticks = (posix_secs + int(EPOCH_DIFF)) * WINDOWS_TICKS
    return winticks

def int_to_bytes(n, minlen=0):  # helper function
    """ int/long to bytes (little-endian byte order).
        Note: built-in int.to_bytes() method could be used in Python 3.
    """
    nbits = n.bit_length() + (1 if n < 0 else 0)  # plus one for any sign bit
    nbytes = (nbits+7) // 8  # number of whole bytes
    ba = bytearray()
    for _ in range(nbytes):
        ba.append(n & 0xff)
        n >>= 8
    if minlen > 0 and len(ba) < minlen:  # zero pad?
        ba.extend([0] * (minlen-len(ba)))
    return ba  # with low bytes first

def hexbytes(s):  # formatting helper function
    """Convert string to string of hex character values."""
    ba = bytearray(s)
    return ''.join('\\x{:02x}'.format(b) for b in ba)

win_timestamp = b'\xc0\x65\x31\x50\xde\x09\xd2\x01'
print('win timestamp: b"{}"'.format(hexbytes(win_timestamp)))
dtime = get_time(win_timestamp)
readable = dtime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')  # includes fractional secs
print('datetime repr: "{}"'.format(readable))

winticks = convert_back(readable)  # includes fractional secs
new_timestamp = int_to_bytes(winticks)
print('new timestamp: b"{}"'.format(hexbytes(new_timestamp)))
```

Output:

```
win timestamp: b"\xc0\x65\x31\x50\xde\x09\xd2\x01"
datetime repr: "2016-09-08 07:35:57.996998"
new timestamp: b"\x80\x44\x99\x4f\xde\x09\xd2\x01"
```

Comment: Given that the OP was truncating to seconds, the lack of 100 ns granularity doesn't really matter; you won't get what you started with, but not because of any limitations of `datetime`.

Comment: Also, why have the `divmod` followed by undoing the `divmod`? You could replace the two lines defining `quotient`, `remainder` and `microsecs` with a single line computing `microsecs` directly: `microsecs = (winticks - WINDOWS_TICKS_TO_POSIX_EPOCH) / WINDOWS_TICKS`

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks for pointing out not needing the `divmod` — it was just a relic of me trying to show the OP how to not throw away the remainder and do a more accurate conversion, unlike in their own code. As to whether the lack of .1 microsec granularity matters: it might if you need to get exactly the same value you started with back for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

If you understand how to perform the conversion in one direction, doing it in reverse is basically using the inverse of each method in reverse order. Just look at the documentation for the modules/classes you're using:

1. `strftime` has [a `strptime` counterpart](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
2. `fromtimestamp` [is matched by `timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) (if you're on pre-3.3 Python, `timestamp` doesn't exist, but you could define `FILETIME_epoch = datetime.datetime(1601, 1, 1) - datetime.timedelta(seconds=time.altzone if time.daylight else time.timezone)` outside the function to precompute a `datetime` that represents the `FILETIME` epoch for your timezone, then use `int((mydatetime - FILETIME_epoch).total_seconds())` to get `int` seconds since `FILETIME` epoch directly, without manually adjusting for difference between `FILETIME` and Unix epoches separately)
3. `divmod` (which you don't really need, since you only use the quotient, not the remainder, you could just do `Epoch = (Ftime - 116444736000000000) // 10000000` and avoid indexing later) is trivially reversible (just multiply and add, with the add being unnecessary if you use my trick to convert to `FILETIME` epoch seconds directly from #2)
4. `struct.unpack` [is matched by `struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack)

I'm not providing the exact code because you really should learn to use these things yourself (and read the docs when necessary); I'm guessing your forward code was written without understanding what it is doing, because if you understood it, the reverse should have been obvious; every step has an inverse documented on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

A basic conversion:

```
from datetime import datetime
from calendar import timegm

EPOCH_AS_FILETIME = 116444736000000000  # January 1, 1970 as MS file time
HUNDREDS_OF_NANOSECONDS = 10000000

def dt_to_filetime(dt):
    return EPOCH_AS_FILETIME + (timegm(dt.timetuple()) * HUNDREDS_OF_NANOSECONDS)
```

The answer is based on this Gist I found: https://gist.github.com/Mostafa-Hamdy-Elgiar/9714475f1b3bc224ea063af81566d873

The Gist adds support for timezones and conversion in the other direction.